# p:fileUpload not working on JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss

I've got Primefaces 5.3 and the following code:

```
<p:fileUpload label="#{res.choosedata}"
  cancelLabel="#{res.abort}" uploadLabel="#{res.txt_import}"
  styleClass="marginBeforeAndBehind"
  fileUploadListener="#{xxxBean.handleFileUpload}"
  mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" sizeLimit="10000000"
  fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/"
  fileLimitMessage="#{res.too_big}"
  update="uploader rfr">
</p:fileUpload>
```

This works perfectly well on TomEE 1.7.2, Windfly 8 and 9 ... and doesn't work on JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21).

The method handleFileUpload is just never called.
My be I need some special config for that?

Comment: any errors in any logging/console?

Comment: nothing.. even in the chrome network tab just one request

Comment: even if I change fileUploadListener="#{xxxBean.handleFileUpload}" to fileUploadListener="#{xxxBean.nonExistantMetod}" I wont even get am exception.

Comment: also nothing in the startup log of the server?

Comment: well... just a normal start...

Comment: If I run the server in debug mode, the handle function is never reached.

Comment: JBoss EAP 6 / AS 7 are not using JSF 2.2. See duplicate for instructions on that.

Comment: I have installed Mojarra 2.2.28 in modules of JBoss. Is this sufficient?